# 3 arm robotic claw

Tags: arduino, robotic-arm, servomotor

I am attempting to design a 3 prong robotic claw for a robotic arm I am working on. I am planning to use sg90 servo motors, but I can't get my current design to work. My current layout is to use one servo motor on a pulley system. The servo motor rotates, which pulls fishing line connected to the end of the claw arms. This is supposed to pull the claws inward(as it does in theory), but the servo motor isn't strong enough to close it fully, and I don't have enough space in the head of claw to fit a larger servo motor inside of it. Is there a different gear system I could use to operate the arms?

Comment: it is unclear how you are actuating the claws .... please provide a diagram

Comment: Typically it is preferred to have the actuation units in the wrist rather than in the tip of the fingers.

Comment: The design I am basing the robot off of is Dum-E from the MCU, and also the actuators are in the wrist, not in the fingertips.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably going to need to use a different gear ratio to get the amount of torque you want. 
You'll get more torque, but the hand won't be able to close as fast.
[Learn more about gear ratios here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear_train)

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics*, tmcd. Please do not post links to spoof sites. I removed your link to a Wikipedia look-alike page. If you want to link Wikipedia content that's fine, but please post a link to the Wikipedia page.